# Firebase to Bigquery unknown dataset generated issue

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I have linked Bigquery to my app through Firebase and it has worked well for more than 3 months. However, couple days ago, a random dataset called "analytics_156951304" was created and then the app data was streamed into this dataset instead of the original dataset that Bigquery created for me when I first linked my app to Bigquery, "my_app_name_IOS". And the table schema was changed too. I checked Stackdriver logging and it said an account called "firebase-measurement@system.gserviceaccount.com" created this job at midnight of my local time. However, I have no clue what happened and how to get my streaming data back to my original dataset, "my_app_name_IOS". Thank you for all the answers!!!

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/51259455/132438, for a handy migration script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase recently scheduled a huge schema migration - your previous queries won't work anymore.

(AFAIK this was communicated via email)

There's a script that helps migrating your previous datasets to the new schema:

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7029846?visit_id=1-636661955728880760-637850888&rd=1#migrationscript

(tho the script won't help with modifying the existing queries)

From the email I got:

> Currently, the data from each app in a Firebase project are exported to a distinct BigQuery dataset in the corresponding BigQuery project. Going forward, the data from each app in a Firebase project will be exported to a single dataset in that BigQuery project. Additionally, the data in this new dataset will follow a new schema.

Comment: thanks so much! I might miss that email.. but now it is all good.